# How do I convert the randomly generated number into its percent version/decimal in C?

Tags: c

How do I convert the randomly generated number into its percent version/decimal? Another question is how do I remove the segmentation fault that keeps on appearing in C?

To give context, this program is about generating a random number. The generated random number afterward will be used as a discount for value.

For example:

Random number generated: `10.0`
Desired outcome from `10.0` = `0.10`
Value Entered = `100`
Price: `100 * 0.10` = `10`

Displayed below is the source code that I am currently working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float fAvtrend;
    int n;
    float fvalue, fDiscount, fAvtr2dec, fnewnum;

    srand(time(NULL));

    fAvtrend = (rand() % 10) + 1 * 0.1;

    printf("%.2f\n", fAvtrend);

    printf("Enter value: ");
    scanf("%f", fvalue);

    fDiscount = fvalue * fAvtrend;

    printf("\nNew converted amount: %.2f", fDiscount);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried everything that I can think of within the bounds of my knowledge regarding C programming.

Comment: What does "its percent version/decimal" mean? Percent of what?

Comment: @MazinoProg You need to write  scanf("%f", &fvalue); instead of  scanf("%f", fvalue);

Comment: See [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](https://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) in the C faq. If you want floating-point spaced 0.1 apart, I would just multiply `int` range by 10 and use a `double` divided by ten. Or were you hoping for a different distribution?

Comment: @MazinoProg,  If `fAvtrend == 100`, do you want to generate random values [0...99] or [0...100]?  If [0...100], do you want the 101 different value to occur at about the same rate, or should the end values occur less often?

Answer (score 2):

```
fAvtrend = (rand() % 10) + 1 * 0.1;
```

As `*` has higher priority than `+`,  `1 * 0.1` will be calculated first and then added to `rand() % 10`.

2. Segmentaion fault:

```
scanf("%f", value);
```

It invokes undefined behaviour as scanf is expecting the pointer to float, not float value. It needs to be `scanf("%f", &fvalue);`

Answer (score 1):

To generate a discount from 1 to 10 percent, you misplaced the `()` in the expression `fAvtrend = ( rand()%10 )+1*0.1`.  You should write:

```
    fAvtrend = (rand() % 10 + 1) * 0.01;
```

Regarding the segmentation fault: you must pass the address of the destination variable in `scanf()`:

```
    scanf("%f", &fvalue);
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    float fAvtrend, fvalue, fDiscount;

    srand(time(NULL));

    fAvtrend = (rand() % 10 + 1) * 0.01;

    printf("Discount: %.2f%%\n", fAvtrend);

    printf("Enter value: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &fvalue) == 1) {
        fDiscount = fvalue * fAvtrend;
        printf("\nNew converted amount: %.2f\n", fDiscount);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I hope you have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the result of `rand()`, which is an integer between 0 and `RAND_MAX` (usually 2147483647, but is depends on the implementation) into a float in range [0, mylimit] (in your case mylimit=100.0) then replace

```
fAvtrend = ( rand()%10 )+1*0.1;
```

with

```
 fAvtrend = ((float)rand() / RAND_MAX) * mylimit;
```

Comment: The value of RAND_MAX is implementation dependent

Comment: @Sushant Yes. I edit my answer, but the code is the same.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question I hope you have a wonderful day.